# How to remove consecutive rows with duplicate data in certain fields (in SQLite)?

Tags: android, sqlite

Let's say for example you have a table like this:

```
-------------------------------
Date        Name          Type
2017-01-01  John          1
2017-01-02  John          1
2017-01-03  Mike          2
2017-01-04  John          1
-------------------------------
```

I want to be able to group by the type to get a result like the following

```
-------------------------
Name          Type
John          1
Mike          2
John          1
-------------------------
```

As you can see the first two rows was grouped because there is no different type in between them, like the thing you see in mobile phones call logs.

How can I achieve that in SQLite?

Comment: How are you ordering this data?

Comment: @iamdave lets say there's a date column and am ordering by that column

Comment: Also, is this `SQLite` or `tsql`?  They are different versions of SQL with different functionality.

Comment: @iamdave its SQLite

Comment: SQLite can't do that.only by java code

Comment: Out of three `John` entities, only one of them gets removed. What qualifies that entry for removal over the other `John`, and which of the three `John` entries qualified for removal while still leaving the other two? EDIT: oh i see, being in the next row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query achieves this by a `NOT EXISTS` for the same `Name` and `Type` values on the previous row (if any). The previous row is found by looking for the maximum date that is strictly less than the date of the current row.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl t2
  WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
  AND t2.Type = t1.Type
  AND t2.`Date` = (SELECT MAX(`Date`)
                   FROM tbl t3
                   WHERE t3.`Date` < t1.`Date`)
);
```

**SQL Fiddle demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0700cb/3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an ordered temp table and some rowid comparisons:

```
sqlite> create table t (date, name, type);
sqlite> insert into t (date, name, type) values ( '2017-01-01', 'John', 1);
sqlite> insert into t (date, name, type) values ( '2017-01-02', 'John', 1);
sqlite> insert into t (date, name, type) values ( '2017-01-03', 'Mike', 2);
sqlite> insert into t (date, name, type) values ( '2017-01-04', 'John', 1);

sqlite> create temp table tp as select date, name, type from t order by date;
sqlite> delete from tp
     where tp.name = (select name from t where t.rowid = tp.rowid - 1)
     and tp.type = (select type from t where t.rowid = tp.rowid - 1);
sqlite> select * from tp;
2017-01-01|John|1
2017-01-03|Mike|2
2017-01-04|John|1
sqlite>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what does this part do `t.rowid = tp.rowid - 1`? Why exactly `- 1`?

Comment: It's comparing to `tp.rowid - 1` to eliminate consecutive (ordered by date) rows with identical name and type.

Comment: But does this work for exactly this example, or will it work for arbitrary input? The "-1" part confuses me

Comment: It works as long as the temp table is created with `order by`... but it depends on SQLite implementation details, so if you can use @Steve Chambers technique and it has acceptable performance, I suggest you use that approach.